# Task menu android

Tags: android, menu

i would like to create an app which has a task menu on the top with buttons for switching back and to the homelayout...

Something like [this](http://www.koisolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/KOI_current_week_en.png).

This menu on the top should be there in the hole app. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). More [docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html).